# Laravel Livewire how to use whereMonth in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

laravel livewire I'm using whereMonth inside foreach but I'm getting error

**error**

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::whereMonth does not exist.
```

**My blade**

```
 @foreach ($this->Data as $key=>$Datas) 
                 <tr>
                 <td >
                     >{{$Datas->where('user_id','=',$Datas[0]->user_id) 
                      ->whereMonth('date','=',$this->MonthToNumber)
                      ->where('status','=', 1 )->count() }} 
                  </td>     
             </tr>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: Do not add query logic in Blade. Use the Controller to manipulate the data and use View just to display it. MVC for a reason.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `whereBetween` method in your application
it might help you

```
$startDate = Carbon::now()->subMonth(); // Get the date one month ago
$endDate = Carbon::now(); // Get the current date

$data = YourModel::whereBetween('created_at', [$startDate, $endDate])->get();
```